# How do we query and fetch all Comments of Salesforce CRM Content?

Tags: apex, soql, content

When we post a Comment on Salesforce CRM Content, where does the comments go? I want to fetch them via SOQL query, which object do they get saved in?

Comment: I tried looking for any standard object still couldn't find where the "Comments" are stored for a Content document record.

Answer (score 1):

Try [FeedComment](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feedcomment.htm) and filter with `RelatedRecordId` as the ContentVersionId and the `CommentType = 'ContentComment'`.

[ContentDocumentFeed](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentfeed.htm) may also be useful.

Comment: No. Couldn't find the Comments in FeedComment object or ContentDocumentFeed object.